# How can I change the text of a back button and remove the < arrow on a tab page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to change the text of the back button and remove the arrow. What I hoped to do was this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
x:Class="HelpHome" 
Title="Home Screen abc" 
NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="< Last screen">
```

When I do this the Title is changed but not the BackButtonTitle.  Instead the BackButtonTitle defaults to the Title of the tab page that I was at before.

I would also like to remove the arrow but I am not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

"The arrow" is actually an iOS specific design implementation.

You would have to write a custom renderer for ContentPage to remove this arrow.
I'm unsure if you can just query the navigationbar for the backbutton and remove the arrow view. You might find something by searching for "ios navigation bar remove back arrow"

The way I'm showing it here, you would remove the button and replace it with a selfmade one:
(In this case you would have to rewire the button events)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage), typeof(CoolPage_iOS))]
namespace YourProject.iOS.Renderer
{
    public class CoolPage_iOS : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            var onlyTextBackButton = new UIBarButtonItem(new UIButton() { Text = "New back Text" } );
            //implement click via: onlyTextBackButton.Clicked += YourClickMethod.....

            ParentViewController.NavigationItem.LeftItemsSupplementBackButton = false;       //Set to false, so the real back button will be taken away
            ParentViewController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems = new UIBarButtonItem[] { onlyTextBackButton };
        }
    }
}
```